# Minimizing two cost functions simultaneously w.r.t. two different parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a model with two scalar cost functions *C_1*(*p*, *t*) and *C_2*(*p*, *t*). My objective is to simultaneously minimize *C_1* with respect to *p* and *C_2* with respect to *t*. In other words, choose *p* and *t* such that

d*C_1*(*p*, *t*) / d*p* = 0

d*C_2*(*p*, *t*) / d*t* = 0

Notice that I *don't* want d*C_1*(*p*, *t*) / d*t* to be 0 or vice versa. In other words, this problem is not equivalent to minimizing some linear combination of *C_1* and *C_2*.

Currently, I'm doing this in by alternating between minimizing *C_1* while passing *p* as the parameter list, then minimizing *C_2* while passing *t*. However this is inefficient and causes problems with momentum-based optimizers. Is there a way to optimize both costs simultaneously in tensorflow without the gradients from *C_1* being applied to *t* and vice versa?

Edit:

A quick example looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

p = tf.Variable(np.random.random(size=(5, 5)))
t = tf.Variable(np.random.random(size=(5, 5)))

C_1 = tf.abs(p) / (1 + t**4)
C_2 = tf.abs(t) / (1 + p**4)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.05)
step1 = optimizer.minimize(C_1, var_list=[p])
step2 = optimizer.minimize(C_2, var_list=[t])
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(20):
  for j in range(5):
     sess.run(step1)
  for j in range(5):
     sess.run(step2)
```

I'm looking for a way to avoid having to alternate between C_1 and C_2, so that I can use momentum-based optimizers (and also because I suspect it will lead to better convergence).

Comment: Your problem is at the optimisation logic and not at the implementation. From my (limited) optimisation experience, if you need to minimise each one, you should do them separately. Otherwise, you should look for the minimum of f1+f2, which makes more sense in most cost optimisation cases.

Comment: Neither of these suggestions works for my case. p and t must be chosen jointly, and I explicitly don't want to just minimize C1 + C2. The optimization logic is hopefully pretty explicit in the question - how to implement it in tensorflow isn't so clear.

Comment: Can you analytically derive expressions for `dC_1(p, t) / dp` and `dC_2(p, t) / dt`? Then you'll have a system of equations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking about the mathematical algorithm to use rather than its programmatic implementation, so it should go to [math.se].

Comment: I guess this is still unclear. The mathematical solution to this problem is trivial. Maybe I need to include code to show that this is not a mathematical question.